# Почему margin-top элемента выпадает из родительского блока?

Tags: html, css

Добрый день.
Подскажите, почему `margin-top` сдвигает элемент относительно `body`, а не родительского блока?

Живой пример **[тут](http://jsfiddle.net/hh2akayc/2/)**.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[[@metamorfoza](/users/33229/metamorfoza)](/users/33229/metamorfoza), почитайте вот эту статью: "**[Схлопывающиеся отступы](http://htmlbook.ru/samlayout/blochnaya-verstka/skhlopyvayushchiesya-otstupy)**".
После прочтения все должно встать на свои места.

> Несмотря на загадочность, схлопывание
> несёт в себе сугубо практическое
> значение и в первую очередь
> предназначено для корректного
> отображения текста. Расстояние между
> абзацами (тег `<p>`) без схлопывания
> увеличится в два раза, тогда как
> верхний отступ первого абзаца и нижний
> отступ последнего абзаца останутся
> неизменными. Схлопывание гарантирует,
> что расстояние в абзацах везде будет
> одинаковым.

Чтобы избежать такого поведения, назначьте родительскому блоку свойство `overflow: auto`.

**[Вот ваш исправленный пример](http://jsfiddle.net/hh2akayc/4/)**.

Answer (score 4):

Выпадение верхнего марджина за пределы родителя хорошо лечится созданием в родителе блока высотой 0 пикселей, который был бы его первым дочерним элементом (размещался в самом начале).

Удобней всего этого добиться с помощью псевдоэлемента `before`:

```
#parent::before {
    content: "";
    overflow: hidden; // обязательно!
    display: block;
)
```